# Hyperlink onClick Event Handler in DataTables using jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to jquery need to use hyperlink onclick event handler.

**What i am trying** : Show Data in a DataTable in order to EDIT|DELETE it. 
                   If you look at the mRender i have added a HyperLink EDIT|DELETE 
So when the user click this hyperlink . It needs to hit the function based on the onclick event which is getbyID(). But i havent figured out why it is throwing an error. I am missing something. Thank you for having a look. Please let me know if i am missing other information.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'GetResourceInfo_Json.asmx/ResourceInfoTable',
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#datatable').dataTable({
                                //Calling DataTable function
                                //destroy: true
                                modal: true,
                                //aaData: response.data,
                                retrieve: true,
                                paging: true,
                                sort: true,
                                searching: true,
                                //scrollY: 600,  // this will change layout
                                data: data,   //pasing data 
                                columns: [   // passing column 
                                    { 'data': 'Xid' },
                                    { 'data': 'yid' },
                                    { 'data': 'LName' },
                                    { 'data': 'FName' },                                  
                                    { 'data': 'UID' },
                                    {
                                      'mRender': function (data, type, row,meta) {
                                       var id = row.UID;                                                                  
                                       return '<a href="#" type="buttonclick" class="button" onclick="getbyID(' + id + ')">Edit</a>' + '|' + '<a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + id + ')">Delete</a>';
                                        }

                                    }
                                ]

                            });
                        }
                    });
                }


//this never gets hit instead it throws an error.
   $('#datatable').on('click', 'getbyID', function ()
        {
          //to do 
          // call asmx and get the resultset from the proc based on id to 
          // populate the field 
          // hide button for insert 
          // update the field by making the call to asmx and proc to update

        });
}
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What is `getbyID`? A function, class or id? Delegate event handler's second parameter would be a `selector`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your code does have extra curly braces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
            url: 'GetResourceInfo_Json.asmx/ResourceInfoTable',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    //Calling DataTable function
                    //destroy: true
                    modal: true,
                    //aaData: response.data,
                    retrieve: true,
                    paging: true,
                    sort: true,
                    searching: true,
                    //scrollY: 600,  // this will change layout
                    data: data,   //pasing data 
                    columns: [   // passing column 
                        { 'data': 'Xid' },
                        { 'data': 'yid' },
                        { 'data': 'LName' },
                        { 'data': 'FName' },                                  
                        { 'data': 'UID' },
                        {
                          'mRender': function (data, type, row,meta) {
                           var id = row.UID;                                                                  
                           return '<a href="#" type="buttonclick" class="button" onclick="getbyID(' + id + ')">Edit</a>' + '|' + '<a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + id + ')">Delete</a>';
                            }

                        }
                    ]

                });
            }
        });
    }  // remove this


    //this never gets hit instead it throws an error.
   $('#datatable').on('click', 'getbyID', function ()
        {
          //to do 
          // call asmx and get the resultset from the proc based on id to 
          // populate the field 
          // hide button for insert 
          // update the field by making the call to asmx and proc to update

        });
    } // remove this
    });
</script>
```

so that it will become:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetResourceInfo_Json.asmx/ResourceInfoTable',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    //Calling DataTable function
                    //destroy: true
                    modal: true,
                    //aaData: response.data,
                    retrieve: true,
                    paging: true,
                    sort: true,
                    searching: true,
                    //scrollY: 600,  // this will change layout
                    data: data,   //pasing data 
                    columns: [   // passing column 
                        { 'data': 'Xid' },
                        { 'data': 'yid' },
                        { 'data': 'LName' },
                        { 'data': 'FName' },                                  
                        { 'data': 'UID' },
                        {
                          'mRender': function (data, type, row,meta) {
                           var id = row.UID;                                                                  
                           return '<a href="#" type="buttonclick" class="button" onclick="getbyID(' + id + ')">Edit</a>' + '|' + '<a href="#" onclick="Delete(' + id + ')">Delete</a>';
                            }

                        }
                    ]

                });
            }
        });

        //this never gets hit instead it throws an error.
       $('#datatable').on('click', 'getbyID', function (){
              //to do 
              // call asmx and get the resultset from the proc based on id to 
              // populate the field 
              // hide button for insert 
              // update the field by making the call to asmx and proc to update

        });
    });
</script>
```

in order for the error to be eliminated.